# Sql split number between rows

Tags: mysql, sql

How should I go about splitting a number equally between rows with correction on last row. Say the number is 100, and there are  11 rows. I will have to add the correction to the last row.
Note: Does not have to be last row, as long as one row includes the correction

`select cost/count from table` 
would work apart from adding the correction to the last row.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you find the last row?

Comment: Could you show an example of what you'd like to get? First 10 rows with 9 and 10 on the last?

Comment: Yes exactly, the last row should include the correction, so be 10. Does not have to be last row, as long as one row includes the correction

Comment: @tichra . . . You may understand what you are asking, but I (for one) do not.  Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I don't get how `"How should I go about splitting a number equally between rows"` translates into `"First 10 rows with 9 and 10 on the last?"`

Comment: no need to go into language technicalities, if you understand the issue

Comment: please see my asnwer. I am responding to the question as it was formulated

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple sub-query. For example

```
select floor(100 / (select count(*) from f)) as number_between_row_count;
```

You can then set a user variable and update the last row, for example;

```
set @number_between_row_count = 0;
select @number_between_row_count:=floor(100 / (select count(*) from f));
update f set bar = @number_between_row_count+1 order by id desc limit 1;
update f set bar = @number_between_row_count where bar is null;
```

Our user variable will hold the calculation (ie: (100 / 5) = 20) so 20 will be written.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

#### Edit

For example, we have the following table;

```
CREATE TABLE `33566497` (
  `number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `t` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test`.`33566497` (`number`, `t`) VALUES ('1', NULL);
INSERT INTO `test`.`33566497` (`number`, `t`) VALUES ('2', NULL);
INSERT INTO `test`.`33566497` (`number`, `t`) VALUES ('3', NULL);
INSERT INTO `test`.`33566497` (`number`, `t`) VALUES ('4', NULL);
INSERT INTO `test`.`33566497` (`number`, `t`) VALUES ('5', NULL);
INSERT INTO `test`.`33566497` (`number`, `t`) VALUES ('6', NULL);
INSERT INTO `test`.`33566497` (`number`, `t`) VALUES ('7', NULL);
INSERT INTO `test`.`33566497` (`number`, `t`) VALUES ('8', NULL);
INSERT INTO `test`.`33566497` (`number`, `t`) VALUES ('9', NULL);
INSERT INTO `test`.`33566497` (`number`, `t`) VALUES ('10', NULL);
INSERT INTO `test`.`33566497` (`number`, `t`) VALUES ('11', NULL);
```

We have 11 records. The first 10 need to have `t = 9` and the last record needs `t = 10`, then we would run;

```
set @number_between_row_count = 0;
select @number_between_row_count:=floor(100 / (select count(*) from `33566497`)); #calc the number (and round down so it's a whole number)
update `33566497` set t = @number_between_row_count+1 order by number desc limit 1; #update the last record to number + 1 because we need 10, not 9
update `33566497` set t = @number_between_row_count where t is null; #set the rest to 9
```

[image]

Comment: what would this set our user variable to?  100/count?

Comment: Depends on the count. If `count` is `10`, then it'll be `100/10 = 10`. Your user variable would be `10`.

Comment: I dont think this will work . My count is 11, so I want first 10 rows to be 9 and the last row 10

Comment: The last row being `PK desc limit 1`?

Comment: yes, it does not strictly have to be last, any row can have the correction. so for a value of 100 , any 1 row should have 10, the rest 9 for a count of 11

Comment: Then issue another `update` query where `x is null`. Check edit

Comment: Hi this is almost correct  now, apart from its not very generic, as the difference will not always be plus 1, it might be  a float value

Comment: How do you calculate the difference?

Comment: total(100) - running total(99). Does that make sense?

Comment: No, not really. What is running total? The amount of rows - 1?

Comment: running total = sum of (total/candidatecount) for all rows. so if its a never ending series or we round the totals, we will get a small rounding error.

Comment: `total` = total rows? What is `candidatecount`, where does that come into it?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Good solution for `100` +1 , please check my solution and tell me if it's ok. I adapted it to work for any number and any number of lines. Asking because your reputation, I would like to see what an experienced SQL user thinks about my code

Answer (score 1):

for one number (any number, just replace it in the set)

```
select 100 / cast((select count(*) from #split) as float) as number_between_row_count
```

UPDATE:
with correction:

```
drop table #split 
drop table #split2

create table #split (lineNumber float, valueTest float)

insert into #split values ('1','20'),('2','25'),('3','50'),
('4','22'),('5','100'),('6', '4'),('7','90'),('8','75'),('9','42'),('10','3'),('11','66')
update #split 
set valueTest = 100
select *, cast(valueTest / cast(round ((select count(*) from #split),0)as int)as int)as div into #split2 from #split 

update #split2
set div = (cast (div as int) + 
(cast (valueTest as int) % cast(div as int)))
where lineNumber = (select top 1 lineNumber  from #split2 order by lineNumber desc)

select * from #split2
```

gives:

```
LineNumber  ValueTest   div
1             100      9
2             100      9
3             100      9
4             100      9
5             100      9
6             100      9
7             100      9
8             100      9
9             100      9
10            100      9
11            100      10
```

Comment: The latest edit doesn't just work for `100` , you can test it with any value and it will work corectly. Just try my query, i also tested it with 200, works. Just change `set valueTest = 100` to whatever number, cheers. Hope it helps

Comment: The update looks good!